# How do I repetitively update a python dictionary without losing original data with key from another dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to update a dictionary created from a txt file with information from another file which comes from a second dictionary. My problem is that every time that I try to update it shortens my file to a 
`single dictionary output" : {my updated output}`, instead of the expected `{my updated output},{my updated output}`

First tried merging the dictionaries and had basically two dictionaries side by side, then tried to update dictionary using `dictionary1.update(dictionary2[key])` and it gave me the "single dictionary output".

```
import re
import os
import glob
asps = []

gbFileNames = list(glob.glob(os.path.join('/Users/schneider/Downloads/Reilly/*.gb')))

gbDict = {}

for myfile in gbFileNames:
    currentfile = open(myfile, 'r')
    for line in currentfile:
        if 'ACCESSION' in line: 
            accn = line.split(' ')[-1].rstrip()
            gbDict[accn] = {'host':'','isolate':''}
        elif 'host=' in line: 
            gbDict[accn]['host'] += line.split('"')[1]
        elif 'isolate=' in line: 
            gbDict[accn]['isolate'] += line.split('"')[1]

seqFileNames = list(glob.glob(os.path.join('/Users/schneider/Downloads/Reilly/*.txt')))

fastaDict = {}

for myfile in seqFileNames:
    currentfile = open(myfile, 'r')
    for line in currentfile:
        if '>' in line:
        # DEFINE GENE ID
            pseudoGeneID = re.search('(?<=gene)\w{1,}', line)
            GeneID = pseudoGeneID.group(0)
        #   fastaDict[GeneID] = {'accn':'','host':'','isolate':'','seq':''} #initiate subdictionary after introducing GeneID variable
            fastaDict[GeneID] = {'accn':'','seq':''} #initiate subdictionary after introducing GeneID variable
            # DEFINE TAXON by accession number
            accn = line.split('|')[1].split('.')[0]
            fastaDict[GeneID]['accn'] += accn.rstrip() # assign accession ID to dictionary using += refer to rstrip down below :)
        else:
            seq = line # here we basically say that if it doesnt start with > we assume it must be a sequence, thus we call the line a seq to make more sense :) 
            fastaDict[GeneID]['seq'] += seq.rstrip()  # rstrip is used here to guarantee that any crap will not come along with your nice sequence data


    fastaDict[GeneID].update(gbDict[accn])  
print fastaDict[GeneID]

fastaDict output = GeneID{accn;seq}
gbDict output = accn{host;isolate}
```

Expected result:

```
updatedDict output = GENEID{accn;seq;host;isolate}
```

Note: GeneID is not unique, as multiple files will have same GeneID, 'accn' combined with GeneID are unique. Ultimately, we want to output a single fasta file per gene with multiple accession numbers. 'accn' is repeated multiple times given the multiple GeneID from a single accn, equating to single genome. Host and isolate are accompanying identifying data which we want to use in the output lines, along with the unique GeneID+accn combinations.

Data structure: 1 accn has multiple sequences each of 1 gene ID, host and isolate.

Comment: keys in dicts are unique

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Hard-code the input file contents, cut down your code to a minimal case, and express the output in Python-compatible terms.

Comment: If you want to have duplicate `accn` then  you need to create a meta Id for each set of key:value pairs. Something like :`{meta_id:{'accn':'acn_value', 'seq': 'seq_value', 'host':'host_val' , 'isolate' :'iso_val'}}` Then you can create as many repeat` accn` values as you choose...I would use some part of accn/geneId to do it so it has relevance and you can iterate through them later.

Comment: The output you list is not a legal Python expression.  As @StephenRauch already mentioned, it appears that you're trying to put multiple copies of a given key into a dict.  This is a violation of the definition of a dict.  If this is the case, you must switch data structures to one that supports the semantics you want.

Comment: An array of dictionaries might be what you are looking for: `[{my updated output},{my updated output}]`